# How to write RewriteRule for a page that resides in a subfolder in root folder using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am writing Rewrite Rule to call a .php file that reside in a folder(folder 1) in root. it says not accessible when i use clean URL. here is the code i have written:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)$ page1.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

root folder contains folder 1 within that i have the page "page1.php".
Here I have written rewrite rule for all the pages that is in root directory. but not able to write code for sub directory(folder 1).

i am newbie for clean URL.

Comment: Please include your entire `.htaccess` file. And what URL(s) are you requesting? You've not specified a path (ie. `/folder1` in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_) - but this could also be set in the `RewriteBase` directive (not shown). What's the significance of `page1` is the `RewriteRule` _pattern_? Do you have a `RewriteEngine` directive?

Comment: _"Here I have written rewrite rule for all the pages that is in root directory"_ - no, you are rewriting everything that starts with `page1/` ... how exactly is that the root directory?

Comment: You also reference "folder 1" (with a space) 3 times in your question text, but the code references `folder1` (no space)? Please clarify.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/publisher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^detail-author/(.*)$ detail-author.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On#RewriteRule ^author-view/(.*)$ "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/publisher/author-view.php?selSort=$1
#RewriteRule ^detail-author/(.*)$ publisher/detail-author.php?aid=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/publisher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^detail-author/(.*)$ detail-author.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Please add this information to your question (you can "edit" your question).